# Function build() only render first array with for loop

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

Currently working on a custom module and I'm trying to render a set of arrays that are created through a *blockForm* and a *blockSubmit* this ones are working correctly. *blockForm* is creating the fields of the form correctly and *blockSubmit* is saving the data of the fields correctly. I tested this several times with positive results. And this two are working with a *FOR* loop.

Now i'm trying to render the data of this *blockForm* with `public function build()` and a FOR loop. But is only rendering the first array and as it is configurated at the moment is should be four arrays.

This is the code:

**FssContentBlock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fss_content\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'Fussion Content Block' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "fss_content",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Fussion Content Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Fussion Content Block"),
 * )
 */

class FssContentBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {//ONLY RENDER FIRST ARRAY...
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
  $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
  $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
  $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');

   for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i ++) {
     $i = $config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i];
     $block1 = array
       (
        $i => array
         (
          '#prefix' => '<p>',
          '#suffix' => '</p>',
          '#markup' => t('@i', array('@i' => $i,)),
         ),
       );
   }

    $block2 = array
      (
        'test' => array
        (
          '#markup' => $qtty . '<p>' . $i . '</p>', //TESTING $qqty VALUE. IT IS CORRECT... BUT WEIRD $i VALUE...
        )
      );
    $allblocks = array_merge($block1, $block2);
  return $allblocks;

/* //THIS CODE WORK... BUT NEED IT TO WORK WITH (FOR - LOOPS)
    $p0 = $config['fss_content_paragraph']['0'];
    $p1 = $config['fss_content_paragraph']['1'];
    $p2 = $config['fss_content_paragraph']['2'];
    $p3 = $config['fss_content_paragraph']['3'];

    $block = array
        (

      'p0' => array
            (
       '#prefix' => '<p>',
       '#suffix' => '</p>',
             '#markup' => t('@p0', array('@p0' => $p0,)),
            ),
      'p1' => array
            (
       '#prefix' => '<p>',
       '#suffix' => '</p>',
             '#markup' => t('@p1', array('@p1' => $p1,)),
            ),
      'p2' => array
            (
       '#prefix' => '<p>',
       '#suffix' => '</p>',
             '#markup' => t('@p2', array('@p2' => $p2,)),
            ),
      'p3' => array
            (
       '#prefix' => '<p>',
       '#suffix' => '</p>',
             '#markup' => t('@p3', array('@p3' => $p3,)),
            )

    );
    return $block;  */
  }//End build

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { //THIS WORK...
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
    $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
    $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');

    $form['fss_content_paragraph'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i ++) {
      $num = $i + 1;
      $form['fss_content_paragraph'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => 'Parrafo N°' . $num,
        '#default_value' => isset($config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i]) ? $config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i] : '',
      );
    }

  return $form;

  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { //THIS WORK...
    parent::blockSubmit($form, $form_state);
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
    $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
    $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');


    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i ++) {
      $this->configuration['fss_content_paragraph'] = $form_state->getValue('fss_content_paragraph',$i);
    }
  }//End blockSubmit

}//End Class
```

**Explanation of how the module work:**

- The module has a configuration option that sets the amount of fields the Administrator user needs.

[image: Quantity of fields]

- Then the form with the amount of fields is created:

[image]

- And this is what my code is rendering at this moment:

[image]

As you can see is rendering the first array but nothing else.

Now, if you take a look at the test i'm making the `$qtty` value is correct witch is the value of the amount of fields i need.

But the last value of `$i` is weird *(last_value_$i = "ABCE")*. Because is taking the first three characters of the first array *(First_array = "ABCD")* and the first character of my second array *(Second_array= "EFGH")*

Any ideas how can i solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you need to define your $block1 variable before your loop block starts?
like $block1 = [];

Comment: Just tested... but no.. didn't work...

Comment: At the `public function build()` Is it possible to replace the FOR loop with a foreach? I've being trying but haven't made it right i think how would be the right way to do it that way?

Comment: Or a foreach nested into a FOR loop.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours... i finally found the correct way to implement this for loop at `function build()`

This is the final code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fss_content\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'Fussion Content Block' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "fss_content",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Fussion Content Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Fussion Content Block"),
 * )
 */

class FssContentBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
  $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
  $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
  $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');


  for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i++) {
    ${'p' . $i} = $config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i];
    $block1['p' . $i]['#prefix'] = '<p>';
    $block1['p' . $i]['#suffix'] = '</p>';
    $block1['p' . $i]['#markup'] = ${'p' . $i};
  }

  return $block1;

  }//End build
  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
    $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
    $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');

    $form['fss_content_paragraph'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i ++) {
      $num = $i + 1;
      $form['fss_content_paragraph'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => 'Parrafo N°' . $num,
        '#default_value' => isset($config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i]) ? $config['fss_content_paragraph'][$i] : '',
      );
    }

  return $form;

  }//End blockForm
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::blockSubmit($form, $form_state);
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    $config2 = \Drupal::config('fss_content.settings');
    $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');
    $qtty = $config2->get('fss_content.paragraphs');


    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtty; $i ++) {
      $this->configuration['fss_content_paragraph'] = $form_state->getValue('fss_content_paragraph',$i);
    }
  }//End blockSubmit

}//End Class
```

Hopefully some day this will help someone else...